# Are all the classes containing business logic, domain objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, business-logic

So I have few doubts regarding calling something as domain object (and eventually placing the class under domain package) or not.

I have a micro-service whose responsibility is to do some calculations (without getting into actual business requirements, all it does is calculate some return of intereset based on given request). Now to achieve the calculations there are certain sub-calculations which need to take place and hence are composed in different classes respectively. But yes, these calculation do not need to be persisted in DB , and neither they have an ID (so definitely not an Entity or Aggregate). However these individual calculator classes (for the lack of terminology) do contain some complex business logic. Now, my question is, do these individual classes still qualify/classify as domain objects or should they be referred to as services ?

Feel free to ask for more clarifications around use case if need be.

Cheers !

Comment: What is the role of these calculations in your domain? You may have very complex infrastructure algorithms, but complexity is not synonym with domain logic.

Comment: It's not the complexity of the calculation only. In scenarios, the behaviour of calculations change, which is governed by business logic. Does this help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, my question is, do these individual classes still qualify/classify as domain objects or should they be referred to as services

From the DDD point of view, in the Domain layer, there are the following terms that could be implemented using classes: `Domain entities`, `Aggregate roots` (a type of `Domain entity`), `Value objects` and `Domain services`.

Because your *things* don't have an `Identity` they cannot be `Domain entities` or `Aggregate roots`. Calculations could be done inside `Value objects` or `Domain services`. `Value objects` contain specific behavior related to values so most probable **your calculations are implemented using `Domain services`**.

From my experience, not every domain class must be a DDD building block, they could be just classes extracted for better maintainability, Single responsibility principle (SOLID in general) etc.

Comment: I'm also more inclined towards having them classified as `Value Objects`, given the fact that on business logic, their behaviour changes (_read polymorphic implementation_). However, my current understanding is that Value Objects are more or less composed by a `Domain Object` itself, which in turn means my `Domain Object` will be one (the final result i'm trying to achieve). Does this approach sound good ?

Comment: @NayabSiddiqui polymorphism can help `Value objects` and `Domain services`. A `Value object` is concerned more about values, data, state and its behaviors about own data (like Money in financial domains, Point in mathematics, UserName in authentication etc) and `Domain objects` apply behaviors on the input data that they receive as parameters. If you could describe your domain maybe we could identify the type of DDD pattern that best matches.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @constantin-galbenu, I think it definitely makes sense to refer them to as `Domain Services`, and your guidelines for classifications definitely help, hence marking this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple test could be asking below questions  -

Does your “calculator” (as you refer it) hold the calculation result as an immutable state? — *if the answer is yes then it is a Value Object.*

Is the “Calculator” stateless and only exposes a “calculate” behaviour which accepts a request & returns a calculation result? — *if the answer is yes then it is a Service, however, the “result” returned by this service may be classified as Value Object.*

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your calculations can fit well either in Value Objects or Domain Services.

How to differentiate? Well, I understand Domain Services as services (well, obvious) with business logic (such as your calculations) that require some kind of external dependency you need to inject in order to get your logic work.

On the other hand, if you can name that business logic as a business concept (i.e. `CustomerFee,` `CustomerCommission,` etc) and you don't need any injected dependency to make it work I would say it's a Value Object.

For instance, imagine that you want to calculate the price of a reservation which depends on the fee you will charge to the customer (among other params):

```
ReservationPrice(CustomerFee customerFee, ItemPrice ItemPrice)
```

Now your `CustomerFee` is also calculated based on (say any variable) something.

This way you are modeling your calculations just with Value Objects which allows you to show in your code all the different business concepts they depend on. Also anyone looking at your code and files structure can get an idea about what you are calculating.